# MySQL innodb Procedure only active once(call serveral times) in a Transaction

Tags: mysql, spring, stored-procedures, transactions

Firstly,I made a MYSQL Procedure to increase a number[+1 every time](there is no TRANSACTION in it), and I called the Procedure n(n>1) times in  a Spring Transaction and got a same number, and the number +1 finally(+n expected)

Secondly, I added TRANSACTION in Procedure and commit atfer +1, and got the same result as above;

Thirdly, I added @Transaction (rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) on the Method A(A calls  Procedure), and call Method A serveral times in Method B, which is annotationed by @Transactional, then I got the same result as above;

Anyone help? can you give me a way to handle it?

Plus:
   the table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `SEQUENCE` (
`ID`  bigint(10) NOT NULL ,
`COUNT`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
`CUR_DATE`  date NOT NULL ,
`READ_ME`  varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

the Procedure in MySQL

```
CREATE DEFINER="root"@"%" PROCEDURE "SEQUENCE_PROCEDURE"(IN _id bigint)
BEGIN
    UPDATE `SEQUENCE` SET `COUNT`=-1,CUR_DATE=now() where `ID`=_id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,CUR_DATE,now())>0 and _id=1;
    UPDATE `SEQUENCE` SET `COUNT`=-1,CUR_DATE=now() where `ID`=_id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,CUR_DATE,now())>0 and _id=2;
    UPDATE `SEQUENCE` SET `COUNT`=`COUNT`+1 where `ID`=_id;
    SELECT * FROM `SEQUENCE` where `ID`=_id;
END
```

the SQL in mybatis

```
<select id="getSequence" parameterType="java.lang.Long" resultMap="baseResult" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call SEQUENCE_PROCEDURE(#{id,jdbcType=BIGINT,mode=IN})}
</select>
```

the Test in project

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testSequence() {
    System.out.println(sequenceService.getId(2L));
    System.out.println(sequenceService.getId(2L));
    System.out.println(sequenceService.getId(2L));
}
```

where

```
public String getId(Long id) {
    Sequence sequence = sequenceMapper.getSequence(id);
    String temp='000000000000'+sequence.getCount();
    return temp.substring(temp.length-12);
}
```

the result of test

```
000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
```

expected result

```
000000000000 000000000001 000000000002
```

add START TRANSACTION and COMMIT in Procedure do not work!

Comment: You need to post the actual code, not just describe it. It's hard to tell precisely what you're doing and what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar  The code has been supplemented above. Can you give me some suggestions？

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure the lines 1 and 2 have specific queries to id 1 and 2 (why?) and double comparison to `_id` variable. Also the third query runs on another table `COUNT`, may be is an error.

I changed the procedure assuming the record already exists, and change the third query to `SEQUENCE` table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SEQUENCE_PROCEDURE(IN _id bigint)
BEGIN

    UPDATE `SEQUENCE` SET `COUNT`=-1,CUR_DATE=now() 
    WHERE `ID`=_id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,CUR_DATE,now())>0;

    UPDATE `SEQUENCE` SET `COUNT`=`COUNT`+1 where `ID`=_id;

    SELECT * FROM `SEQUENCE` where `ID`=_id;
END
```

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake on replaceing the word to avoid leakaging business infomation. I fixed it as your comment and I cannot get the expected result.

Comment: What is the content of your `SEQUENCE` table?

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SEQUENCE`;
CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (
  ID bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  COUNT int(11) NOT NULL,
  CUR_DATE date NOT NULL,
  READ_ME varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: I was asking for the records, not the structure.

Comment: INSERT INTO `SEQUENCE` (`ID`, `COUNT`, `CUR_DATE`, `READ_ME`) VALUES ('2', '-1', '2018-08-03', 'init count monthly');
INSERT INTO `SEQUENCE` (`ID`, `COUNT`, `CUR_DATE`, `READ_ME`) VALUES ('1', '-1', '2018-08-27', 'init count daily');